# Adding quanitity to add to cart button

Tags: paypal, addition

I am using a Add to Cart button in paypal on my HTML website.

What I would like to do is add a quantity drop down menu that when someone puts in they want to buy say 5 of an item it changes the Shopping cart total to that 5 times the unit price. For example a I have a variable sized items at the a $10.00 price but they want to order 5 of them so instead of the Shopping cart only showing 1 item at $10.00 I want it to show  5 items totally $50.00. I don't want the customer to have to click the add to cart button 5 individual time.

I am also using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dynamic buttons which updates the add to cart buttons with javascript, you can
use [minicartjs](http://minicartjs.com/) which is a third party plugin.

[Demo](https://www.paypaltech.com/vimal/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below line of code in your existing add to cart button to provide the drop down for the quantity selection :

```
Select Quantity
<select name="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Vimal's suggestion is good as it will provide you the option for more customization